# Flutter, Gradle not working except on https

Tags: gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

guess your day is going on well!

Just Formatted my system from windows 8 to windows 10 and i want to quickly dive into flutter, so i start using it, i then download android studio.

I got Git downloaded, Flutter downloaded (and i add the path of the flutter sdk to the user path), I downloaded Android studio and then install flutter and dart plugin.

Everything is working fine, run `flutter --version, flutter doctor` and it work well.

The Challenge
Once i click on the run or debug button in android studio, i do get these error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > download.flutter.io
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

For hours, i tried different approach, i still get the above errors, so i decided to browse the following domain which are present in the error
1) gradle.org
2) flutter.io

behold it was not working, i got This page isn’t working {domain name} didn’t send any data.

But when i add the https:// to the above domain name, it work right in the browser

**My Question Now is**

How do i add https:// to gradle properties or plugin in android

Answer (score 12):

I was also getting this same issue after upgrading to flutter 1.17

```
maven {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
      }
```

Adding this to android->build.gradle->allprojects->repositories solved the issue.

The main cause of this issue seems to be my country has blocked some google APIs. I have totally no clue why would they do this.

Comment: Thank you. work for me perfectly. After search about that got problem. Some country block some google feature, that why get this issue.

Answer (score 6):

In my situation

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

helps me

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue for couple of hours. After adding maven to build.gradle it was also showing error. at the end solved by executing following steps -

```
- add to build.gradle under repositories in both buildscript and allprojects section

maven {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
    }

- and also run on command line 'flutter pub cache repair'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below to buildscript and allprojects.

```
maven {
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
```

Then run `'flutter pub cache repair'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes Yes Yes and Yes!

After the long hours spent trying to make things work on android studio with flutter, these below were the things i did and honestly i don't even know which one made it work.

> I got some answer from github
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48494 and i downloaded
>   all the android sdk version (ALL) and i restart my system and try it
>   again voila, Flutter Program ran on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly due to some errors in your network or firewall or the proxy you have enabled i your system. Try connecting to the **Mobile internet Via USB Tethering and run the flutter Application.**
*This work perfectly and uninstalling & re-installing the android studio or flutter SDK doesn't solve it.*

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue now in 2023 and maven apparently changed its endpoint once again.

```
maven {
  url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
}
```

added to `repositories` works for me.