# Problem with flutter plugin (Image Cropper)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm creating a app which will work with images, some of them will need to be cropped and some not. I have added the library:

```
image_cropper: ^1.3.1
```

I have installed the dependencies in android manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        // This is wat I had to add as said in the pub.dev from icon cropper
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But when I run my application I receive the following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.7.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :image_cropper
      > Could not resolve com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.7.
         > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.7/ucrop-2.2.7.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/yalantis/ucrop/2.2.7/ucrop-2.2.7.pom'.
               > Connect to www.jitpack.io:443 [www.jitpack.io/149.56.28.39] failed: Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is my settings.gradle:

```
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.
 
include ':app'
 
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()
 
def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}
 
plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

I have multiDex enabled too.

Answer (score 0):

I have image_cropper working, an example for you to check and compare if is everything ok.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label=""
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
           
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You haven't added the line?
`<activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>` In the pub.dev it tels to add this line on the Android manifest

Comment: Yes I have, it's the first ```<activity>```.

Comment: Oh, I will attempt to insert there too

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have a good internet connection and then build the project again

Comment: I have a good internet connection, it is with cable not wireless and it's working great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663760/flutter-gradle-not-working-except-on-https
Refer to this. It would help you

Comment: I will attemp to do so