# Flutter submodule in Android project - packages not resolved

Tags: android, flutter, maven, gradle, flutter-module

I am trying to add a Flutter module to my Android project.
For that, I follow the [relevant flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup), and everything seemingly works fine.

However, when I run a Gradle sync after following all the steps in above link, the sync returns the following warnings

```
Failed to resolve: io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab
Failed to resolve: io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab
Failed to resolve: io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab
Failed to resolve: io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab
Failed to resolve: io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab
```

It seems it cannot find some needed packages in any of the repositories I have specified.
And indeed, I cannot use

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment;
```

from my Android Java code.

What repository do I have to specify to make sure the needed packages are found?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

I looked through a bunch of questions here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to really match the problem I ran into.
The closest would be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663760/flutter-gradle-not-working-except-on-https), but its answer did not *quite* work in my case.

Instead I stumbled upon [this blog post](https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01650-8e47c7be-9b32-4c14-9752-43e633d86b0b), where it is recommended to add the following repository:

```
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io" }
    }
```

In my case, I added the repository to `settings.gradle` in the host Android project (not in the one generated by Flutter). Where you add the repository may vary in your case, and I am not 100% confident that this is the best place.

However, this indeed fixes the problem for me. The packages are found, and I can use the Flutter module as expected.

#### Details

The repository mentioned in [the SO question I mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663760/flutter-gradle-not-working-except-on-https) is accessed via `http` which may be an issue for some.
Accessing it with `https` give the following in Firefox:

```
Websites prove their identity via certificates. 
Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for download.flutter.io. 
The certificate is only valid for the following names: 
*.storage.googleapis.com, *.googleapis.com, commondatastorage.googleapis.com, 
*.commondatastorage.googleapis.com, storage.googleapis.com, storage.mtls.googleapis.com,
 *.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com, *.content-storage.googleapis.com, 
*.content-storage-p2.googleapis.com, *.content-storage-upload.googleapis.com, 
*.content-storage-download.googleapis.com, *.storage-upload.googleapis.com, 
*.storage-download.googleapis.com
```

This indicates to me that `https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io` is the correct URL to use for the Maven repository.

Comment: had the same issue, and i followed the blog post you shared here, and it builds successfully! for me, I had to add the maven repo at the build.gradle under 'allproject'