# build.gradle Error " Build failed with an exception." (FLUTTER)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
* Where:
Build file 'D:\flutter proekts\untitled23\android\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method url() for arguments [http://download.flutter.io] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am trying this

```
url 'http://download.flutter.io'
```

into

```
build.gradle
```

file :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Then flutter run in terminal. I got this error! How to fix this error? Excuse me! I am a beginner in English.  Please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663760/flutter-gradle-not-working-except-on-https

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Gradle that the URL is pointing to a Maven repository, like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```